# Future function was called on null (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

So I'm writing an quiz app and I need to get defined amount of questions from firestore. So i created two files data provider file and repository file, and that's how they look:
**Data Provider**

```
class TestProvider {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<Map> getQuestionFromFirebase(String documentId) async {
    Map mappedQuestion;
    await _firestore
        .collection('questions')
        .doc(documentId)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => mappedQuestion = snapshot.data());
    return mappedQuestion;
  }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class TestRepository {
  final int amountOfQuestions;
  TestRepository({
    @required this.amountOfQuestions,
  });

  TestProvider _testProvider;

  Future listOfQuestions() async {
    List<int> range = numberInRange(amountOfQuestions);
    List<Question> listOfQuestions;
    for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfQuestions; i++) {
      listOfQuestions.add(Question.fromMap(
          await _testProvider.getQuestionFromFirebase(range[i].toString())));
    }
    return listOfQuestions;
  }
}
```

The error i get:

```
E/flutter ( 5186): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getQuestionFromFirebase' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5186): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 5186): Tried calling: getQuestionFromFirebase("3")
```

The funny thing about it is the fact that when i call fuction from provider i don't get error. Problem begins when I'm using it from repo class. Any idea how to fix it? I don't want to use FutureBuilder any time I want to use it in widget. I want to transform snapshot into my question model.

Comment: Maybe you are missing to initiate your ```TestProvider``` ? ```TestProvider _testProvider = TestProvider();```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TestRepository` code it's not clear where you are instantiating `TestProvider _testProvider;` member.

The error message is clear **The method 'getQuestionFromFirebase' was called on null**. So there is no instance of `TestProvider` class and `_testProvider` is a null pointer.

Grant `TestProvider _testProvider = TestProvider();` in your code as said by @ikerfah and you will have no issues in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much is working just fine :)